# View deleted content with less than 10k

Tags: bug, deleted-questions, flags

Possible bug? Feature? Overlooked detail that doesn't matter?

Users with less than 10k reputation can view (at least part of) deleted questions that they have flagged.

As a <10k user:

- Go to your user page
- Click on the number of helpful flags
- Find a question that has been deleted
- Put your mouse over the title of the question
- View deleted content

Is this intentional?

> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqOG9.png]

Comment: This is a marginal issue.

Comment: Additionally, should 10k and 10k-tools really be synonyms? I'm sure there is a lot of overlap, but this question is one example where 10k would be relevant, but 10k-tools is definitely not relevant.

Comment: If you flagged for deletion, wouldn't you have already had access to the original content anyway?

Comment: Yes, but the same could be said for any deleted question you've asked.

Comment: I guess my point is that it's not revealing anything you haven't seen before.

Comment: I can't reproduce this on Google Chrome 19.0.1084.52, on Linux.

Comment: I'm reproducing pretty consistently with IE8 on Windows 7

Comment: No repro on [my Gaming.SE profile](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/7364/the-annoying-pyro)

Comment: Well you already saw it before you deleted it, and you only see the title (and maybe the mouseover?)

Comment: Hm, it looks like it only works on Meta. Couldn't repro on SO or english.SE

Comment: @Jim That's probably because you mostly flag questions on MSO. The snippet preview only works for questions, not answers. On any site.

Comment: @lunboks Seems you are correct. Checked SO, and I can see it for questions but not answers. Doesn't look like I have any MSO answers flagged for comparison.